# How to log all exceptions in python 3

Tags: logging, exception, python-3.x, error-logging

There are a lot of exception I don't want to catch, I want them to stop processing, but, I still want the stack trace in the log file. Is there a way to setup a logger so that it automatically logs all exceptions?

Right now I am writing things like this a lot:

```
try:
  blah
except:
  logging.exception('doing blah')
  raise
```

which take up a lot of time and space + it'll only log the exceptions for which I have a try clause for, not the other ones.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use decorators to wrap individual functions and methods with code that logs any uncaught exception.

This means one additional line of code in front of any function definition that should do this logging. Advantage is: Can be quickly added and removed.

The decorator also could get arguments. For example you could specify the base class of those exceptions that you want to log.

[Here's a basic question & concise answer on how to write decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/739654/923794).

Answer (score 0):

You could put a catch all handler at the topmost level of your code:

```
try:
  everything
except:
  logging.exception('unhandled')
  raise
```

Comment: Tanks, but I was hopping for something I could set in the module where I build my logger, since I import that module in all my programs.

Answer (score 0):

'sys.exc_info()' helped with 'text' from most common exceptions viz., (1)'NameError'; (2) 'FileNotFoundError';(3)'ZeroDivisionError' and (4)'IndexError':...may be more too
#============================================

```
import sys
try:  
    #<Anything here>
except:
    print(str(sys.exc_info()))
```

#============================================
Example:

```
import sys
try:
    #Unprompt one at atime
    z = (9/0)#ZeroDivisionError
    #f = open("I:\Invalidpath\inventory2.txt", "r")#FileNotFoundError
    #f = open("I:\validpath\inventory2.txt", r)#NameError
    #==========
    #a = [1, 2, 3]
    #print("Second element = %d" % (a[5]))#'IndexError'
    #==========
except:
    print(str(sys.exc_info()))
```

#==============================================